# Speeding up loop-rich Matlab function to calculate temperature distribution

Tags: performance, matlab, loops, vectorization

I would like to speed up this function as much as possible in Matlab.
This is part of a bigger simulation project, and as it is one of the most called functions within the simulation, this is crucial.

For now, I tried generating a MEX file, but the speed was not better.

Vectorizing seems difficult (but would be beneficial due to the nested loops), given the non-linear operations.

```
function y = mixing(T,dis,rr,n)  
%% =================================================================== 
%  input: temperature of cells array T, distance array dis, number of cells
%         n, mixing ratio r
%
%  output:  new temperature array
%
%  purpose: calculates the temperature array of next timestep
%  ===================================================================

for j = 1:n
    i = 1;
    r = rr;
    while i < dis(j)+1 && j+i <= n
        if (dis(j) < i) 
            r = r*(dis(j)-floor(dis(j))); 
        end
        d = T(j+i-1);
        T(j+i-1) = r*T(j+i) + (1-r)*T(j+i-1);
        T(j+i) = r*d + (1-r)*T(j+i);
        i = i + 1;
    end
end

y = T;
end
```

- Any ideas on how to speed-up this Matlab function?
- Inputs: `T` is a `10`x`1` `double`, `dis` is a `10`x`1` `double`, rr is a `1`x`1` `double`, and `n` is a `1`x`1` `integer` value.
- **Example values**: `T = random('unif',55,65,10,1); dis = repmat(0.1,10,1); rr = rand; n = 10;`

---

What I'm trying to compute with this is the degree of temperature mixing between water layers, given by the equations for `T(j+i-1)` and `T(j+i)`.

This must be calculated for all [image: formula], this is for all the layers, at all timesteps (note that [image: formula] are the total number of water layers).

Comment: Would using `parfor` be of any use? http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some exact inputs, i.e. values for `T`, `dis` and `rr`?

Comment: the outer loop can not be changed for a `parfor` one, due to the way the variable `T` is used (this error is shown by Matlab when trying to change them)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor sure can do

Comment: @knedlsepp I didn't delete any questions. I posted the same on Code Review, but as the number of Matlab users there is very small I decided to put it here as well.

Comment: @knedlsepp this has nothing to do with oceans! It is a layer model for electric water heaters, where `T` is the temperature in each one of the `n` layers, and the dynamics are nonlinear, with a mixing ratio `r`. This mixing ratio is also time varying, and dependant of a distribution stored in `dis`. This code was given to me (legacy code in engineering), and I have little to no understanding to what's going on in here, only thing, in the overall simulation it is one of the most time-consuming functions (and called **a lot**)

Comment: @titus.andronicus: I'm sorry, I may have not remebered this correctly.

Comment: @titus.andronicus: I'm sorry about my misjudgement. I did find the original question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73594
So on compiling your mex files, turning on the optimization flags didn't help either?

Comment: @knedlsepp no, the computation time was roughly the same as what I had

Comment: If you have the resources and time and maybe a bit of skills, you can look to implement it on CUDA. So, with it, you can keep the frequently used `d`, `T(j+i-1)` and `T(j+i)` in registers for fastest access and keep `T` in shared memory (if the size permits). This could really speed it up for you!